# MongoDB poor read performance

Tags: mongodb, performance, database

I have a simple data set, a few collections, not more than 20
documents in each, in MongoDB 2.0 (previously 1.8). I'm getting poor
results when it comes to querying data (at least I think they could be
much better looking at http://mongoid.org/performance.html). At first,
I though that the mapper I use in Ruby (Mongoid) was the problem, but
I made some more tests and it seems more related to the database
itself.

I've made a simple benchmark where I query the same document 10000
times by its ID, first using the Ruby Mongo driver, then Mongoid. The
results:

```
              user     system      total        real
driver    7.670000   0.380000   8.050000 (  8.770334)
mongoid   9.180000   0.380000   9.560000 ( 10.384077)
```

The code is here: https://gist.github.com/1303536
The machine I'm testing this on is a Core 2 Duo P8400 2.27 GHz with 4
GB of RAM running Ubuntu 11.04.
I also made a similar test using pymongo to check if the problem lies
in the Ruby driver, but the result was only slightly better (5-6 s for
10000 requests).

The bsonsize of the document I'm fetching is 67. It has some small
embedded documents, but not more than 100. Some of the embedded
documents refer documents from other collections by ID, but AFAIR this
relationship is handled by the mapper, so it shouldn't influence the
performance. Fetching this document directly in the database with `explain()` results in millis = 0.

The odd thing is that the HDD LED keeps blinking all the time during
the tests. Shouldn't this document be cached in RAM by Mongo after
first read? Is there something obvious I could be missing? Or is this
not a poor result at all (but comparing with http://mongoid.org/performance.html
it does seem bad)?

Comment: It would be useful if you shared all of your code. At a glance, it seems that you are doing a lot more than just retrieve a tuple within the loop. For one thing, you appear to repeatedly select the collection.

Comment: What more code than this gist should I share? Let's dismiss the Mongoid test - it's irrelevant here. So, the whole code is in the gist. The Python version is the same, I guess, just in case I put it [here](https://gist.github.com/1303871).

Comment: Do you see faults/sec in your mongostat run during this? Either way there's a lot of different reasons why this could happen. Try rewriting your test in JSON/JS so even people not familiar with Mongoid can help you.

Comment: A simple benchmark in JS is [here](https://gist.github.com/1306405). Running this (`time mongo db_name file.js`) takes 2 minutes with a fresh database that has 13 objects. Compared to results from [here](http://mongoid.org/performance.html) it seems ridiculously slow even when taking into account the hardware difference (unless I'm misinterpreting something). `mongostat` shows no faults, the only thing which seems odd to me is that net out never exceeds 2-3MB/s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dropped and recreated the database. Maybe it was because of going from 1.8 to 2.0. Anyway, the HDD led stopped blinking and everything is now 2-3x times faster.

I also looked carefully at the test that was used to benchmark Mongoid and this result (0.001s) is just for one find(), not a million. I told the Mongoid's author that I think it's not stated clearly on the web site that the number of operations applies only to some of them.

Sorry for the confusion.